# Finding the path to every file in a directory

Tags: python, file, directory

I am currently trying to go through a series of folders to find a certain file within each folder. The file follows the same naming convention in every folder, but some folders have sub-directories and thus the path to that file varies in too many ways to build unique cases. In some cases there are more than one file that I need (though they are found the same way), hence the list to store possibly multiple correct files.

Generally, these are the cases I need to handle:
root/file
root/file2
root/subdir/file
root/subdir/subdir2/.../file

My code as is:

```
def findFile(inputpath, tablenumber):
    f = []
    target = 'string_to_find'
    for path, subdirs, files in walk(inputpath):
     for name in files:      
       if target in name:
         f.append(join(inputpath, name))
    print(f)
```

While I manage to find the files, I'm unable to find the paths to those files except for the trivial case where it is in the parent directory. Is there a way to adapt my current solution for this? Or might I need to approach it with different os methods?

Comment: Use `f.append(join(path, name))` instead.

Comment: I 100% overlooked that and probably would have continued to searching for more complex solutions... thanks!